# .htaccess rewrite rule for dynamic sub folders

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to rewrite rule in htaccess for subfolders created dynamically `/folder/folder/folder/folder/index.php?product=car`

i want like this `folder/folder/folder/folder/product/car`

code

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^product=1$
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?  index.php?product=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^((?:[^/]+?/)*)product/(.+)$ $1index.php?product=$2 [L,NC]
```

Comment: @Lm ieee it doenst work. It needs to catch the url since folders are dynamic